# Optimize netezza table

Tags: optimization, netezza

I'm using Netezza database. I have 2 table, and I want to know which is better (run query faster, size lower, etc...)

Table 1: has 3 columns and 6 rows

[image: table 1]

Table 2]: (restructure from table 1): has 4 column and 3 rows

[image: table 2]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

youll get no definite answer to questions like that, there are only a lot of pros and cons to consider, but I guess that is what you ask for :)

'To de-normalize or not to... that is the question':

Normalize:

- (Pro) easier to update (add one new month)
- (pro) perhaps better compression (since Netezza does column compression)
- (pro) most standard frontend tools will 'understand' the data model
- (con) year-to-date report-queries may take 12 times longer in December compared to January (personally I would add a YTD_value column)

De-normalize 
  - (pro) perhaps better extract performance since the number of joins is lower, but only if almost all ID's are present in every month 
  - (con) much more difficult to load since you will have to choose between insert and update all the time.
  - (con) most frontend tools will have to be 'taught' how to query the data model
  - (pro) easy to calculate 'joiners/leavers' against previous month (but not in January)

There are probably more :)

Personally I would go for the normalization option, with a Pre-calculated YTD or 'running 12 months' of necessary ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean Normalize is table 1 or table 2?

Comment: I'd say "only 3 rows or 6 rows? Netezza won't care."  :) But Lars gives the more thoughtful, useful answer.

Comment: Table1 = normalize